# KDE 5.36.0 switching keyboard layouts re-enabling possible?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout

After rebooting today my keyboard switching is no longer working, using `meta + space`. It is still configured under `System Settings` -> `Input Devices` -> `Keyboard` -> `Layouts` 
Clicking the language icon in the system tray still works - but is inconvenient.

```
kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.6.1
KDE Frameworks: 5.36.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

I also tried editing `sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard` but problem is probably shortkey related - not that the layouts are not enabled.
Any ideas?

Comment: FYI:  Kubuntu 16.04 LTS was a flavor, and as such reached EOL April-2019  (https://kubuntu.org/news/trusty-14-04-lts-end-of-life-and-end-of-kubuntu-support-for-xenial-16-04-lts/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) so consider upgrading to 18.04 if your box is online.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard` and changing the layout languages (in my case to English and German)
`XKBLAYOUT="us, de"` required a reboot to take effect.